Tufte Class and Margins
I have recently gotten acquanited with the tufte document class and I love its style very much; the only thing that bothers is the side margin use, even though I understand that it is exactly what the tufte class is known for.
Is there a way to not have margin with the exact same style of the tufte class? Or maybe the margins only appear when I would like to write something in them (like a footnote).
I really like this style so I would would really like to use it. If you suggest an alternative class, please let me know which one I could use!

Instead of pointing out what you do not like by the tufte class (the margins are in my opinion a big part of that style), maybe you can mention a few things that you do like and that you would like to see covered in an answer.

I quite like the other features, in particular, the font (this is the most likeable part for me), the design on the section headings and organization was well; I just want to be able to use the entirety of the page, like in full width and add margins only when I want sidenotes.

You can write full-width paragraphs in the tufte class by enclosing them in:
\begin{fullwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{fullwidth}

Rough example:
\documentclass[nohyper,titlepage,nols]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{test.jpg}
    \caption[test]{Test}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Section}

\lipsum[3]

\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[1]
Body with note\sidenote{Classic sidenote here}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{fullwidth}

\lipsum[3]
\section{Section}

\lipsum[4]

\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}


Note, however, that the tufte class transforms footnotes into sidenotes, so if you're planning to use footnotes at all, this solution might not suit your needs.

Hi thank you so much for your response! Just a quick question: wouldn't this be inconvenient as I would have to do this for each paragraph? Also, does fullwidth apply across pages?

@PCeltide No need to do that for each paragraph. It applies across pages. It might not look as pleasant as you think, though. I edited my answer to give a rough example.
